# How to get the transaction Status from HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jta

I am trying to upgrade my spring transaction manager from **JtaTransactionManager** to **HibernateTransactionManager**. In JTA TransactionManager we have one method which gives the status of current transaction. Based on the status we are doing some operations. The implementation is as follows :

```
private void checkTransactionStatus(TransactionStatus status){
             if(status instanceof DefaultTransactionStatus) {
                DefaultTransactionStatus transactionStatus = (DefaultTransactionStatus) status;
                if(transactionStatus.getTransaction() instanceof JtaTransactionObject){
                    JtaTransactionObject txObject = (JtaTransactionObject) transactionStatus.getTransaction();
                    int jtaStatus;
                    try {
                        jtaStatus = txObject.getUserTransaction().getStatus();
                        if(jtaStatus==Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK){
                            // logic heare
                        }
                    } catch (SystemException e) {}
                }
             }
           }
```

I want to replace this method with HibernateTransactionManager specific code. I analyzed and found that, HibernateTransactionManager is using   **HibernateTransactionObject** as transaction object. But, unfortunately it's a private inner class that I can't use to get the status. Then I tried to use the parent class **JdbcTransactionObjectSupport**. But, I don't know how to get the status from this parent class object.

```
private void checkTransactionStatus(TransactionStatus status){
         if(status instanceof DefaultTransactionStatus) {
            DefaultTransactionStatus transactionStatus = (DefaultTransactionStatus) status;
            if(transactionStatus.getTransaction() instanceof JdbcTransactionObjectSupport){
                JdbcTransactionObjectSupport txObject = (JdbcTransactionObjectSupport) transactionStatus.getTransaction();
                //how to get the current status ?
            }
         }
       }
```

Comment: Seems overly complex, use a `TransactionSynchronizationManager` to register your callbacks instead, saves you calling this method as you will receive the callbacks regardless of the used technology.

Comment: Are you only interested in STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK or different values as well?

Comment: @Marvin.. as of now.. I need only STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has a mechanism for receiving callbacks. You can implement the [`TransactionSynchronization`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html) interface (or easier extend the [`TransactionSynchronizationAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html)). You probably want to implement the `afterCompletion(int)` method and put your logic in there.

```
public class MyTxCallback extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        if (status==STATUS_ROLLED_BACK) {
            //logic here.
        }
    }

}
```

You can then bind that to the transaction by calling the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` when a transaction is started. Now when the transaction is done the method will be called and you can do your logic (regardless of the underlying transactional resource used).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `HibernateTransactionManager` you can get the current transaction state from the Hibernate Session:

```
LocalStatus status = session.getTransaction().getLocalStatus();
```

and the `LocalStatus` has the following states:

```
public enum LocalStatus {
    /**
     * The local transaction has not yet been begun
     */
    NOT_ACTIVE,
    /**
     * The local transaction has been begun, but not yet completed.
     */
    ACTIVE,
    /**
     * The local transaction has been competed successfully.
     */
    COMMITTED,
    /**
     * The local transaction has been rolled back.
     */
    ROLLED_BACK,
    /**
     * The local transaction attempted to commit, but failed.
     */
    FAILED_COMMIT
}
```